# Системы сборки проектов C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, c, visual-studio-code

Думаю над тем как обустроить быт разработки на C/C++ под линукс. На CLion денег жалко. QtCreator просто не нравится. Есть идея все забацать в VSCode. Я смотрел - там очень крутое автодополнение есть. Осталось лишь настроить сборку. Помнится еще на винде я проекты на C/C++ делал или в Visual Studio или в QtCreator и там конечно все билдилось нажатием одной кнопки, ну а если без этого то придется осваивать системы сборки.

Во первых хотелось бы выяснить какие вообще бывают? Я знаю про CMake, но может существуют еще какие-то более современные? Чем вообще сейчас пользуются то чаще?

Во вторых касательно конкретно CMake. Я так понял что он только создает проект, но не компилирует. Для компиляции еще make надо вызывать... А можно это как-то автоматизировать? Юзать таски в VSCode? И еще в Visual Studio у всех проектов была Debug (вроде с какой-то отладочной информацией) и Release версии. Тут также? Или тут только одна?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66469/discussion-on-question-by-dark-byte----c-c).

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/2w40l9/build_systems_for_c_projects/), кроме [CMake](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/) существуют:

1. [Tup](http://gittup.org/tup/)
2. [Cuppa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cuppa)
3. [Maiken](https://github.com/Dekken/maiken)
4. [Shakebuild](http://shakebuild.com)
5. [Mesonbuild](http://mesonbuild.com/index.html)

Comment: чего люди не придумают, что бы только телплый ламповый make не использовать.:)

Comment: А что из этого реально имеет скажем так большой процент пользователей? Насколько я понимаю CMake наше все? А на это все остальное приходятся считанные проценты юзеров?

Comment: @DarkByte, да забейте вы на эти проценты. Пользуйтесь тем, что лучше подходит лично вам.

Answer (score 1):

Во многих крупных проектах почти всегда можно увидеть скрипты сборки CMake и Autotools. Да, они генерируют make-файл. Самый популярный, по моему мнению, CMake, но его ругают за синтаксис.

```
Но может существуют еще какие-то более современные?**
```

Самый "молодой" - qbs от Qt, но я с ним не работал, сравнить не могу с CMake.

```
Юзать таски в VSCode?
```

Этот плагин все кнопочки нужные тебе сделает: [vscode-cmake-tools](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools)

> Release и Debug

Это настройка компилятора, в CMake настраивается переменной [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE). Плагин выше с этим поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Ответы, данные на StackOverfollow ранее, поголовно являются устаревшими. На текущий момент, обладает относительно вменяемой интеграцией автодополнения синтаксиса файлов конфигурации системы сборки только [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) от Google. Так же есть клевые плагины для VS Code, реализующие интеграцию в средства разработки C++ от Microsoft - работает IntelliSense

[image: Расширение Bazel от Devon Carew]
Расширение Bazel от Devon Carew

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Расширение Bazel Tools от Dirk Mueller

Заявлено применение в Google, Huawei, Dropbox и Pinterest. Официальный сайт проекта: https://bazel.build/

По поводу других средств сборки: не рекомендую! У CMake синтаксис на любителя, а Gradle(C++ plugin) не только медленная, но и до сих пор в глубокой альфе. В сочетание с тем, что её дублируют в стандартных репозиториях дистрибутивов Linux, это может породить хаус версий!

[image: Graddle: все методы имеют статус "incubating"]